# How to toggle div and up-down arrow heads using css only

Tags: css

I would like to toggle div and up-down arrow heads using css only. I would like also a link at the bottom of the div to close the div (Less)

These are some problems which I am facing -

1. The less link to close the div at the bottom does not work in firefox and internet explorer
2. The arrows besides the toggle is not showing besides the heading but underneath the heading and they do not show at all in firefox and internet explorer
3. A faint peculiar outline is coming on the up-down arrowhead elements
4. Edit - The toggle inbox is also not hiding in Firefox and internet explorer

As suggested by Jibbow, I have replaced the "a" tags with "span" tag for the 
less link and it is now working

Here is my code -

Html -

```
<label class="label" for="_1">Stack OverFlow - Aim of Website - To discuss   
good questions about good code and code development</label>

<input class="toggle-inbox" id="_1" type="checkbox" >

<div id="text-contents-details1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer   
adipiscing. &nbsp;&nbsp;

<label href="#clear" class="less" for="_1"><span id="less" style="color:darkorange;" class="arrow-  
less">Less</span></label>
</div>
```

Css -

```
.label {
float:left;
font-size: 29px; 
}

.toggle-inbox {
display: none;
visibility: 0;
float: left;
}

label +.toggle-inbox {
cursor: pointer;
display: block;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 21px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
float:left;
}

label + .toggle-inbox + div#text-contents-details1 {
display: none;
margin-bottom: 10px;
clear :both;
}

label + .toggle-inbox:checked + div#text-contents-details1 {
display: block;

 }

 label +.toggle-inbox:after {

 background-color:white ;
 border-right: 3px solid black; 
 border-bottom: 3px solid black; 
 width: 10px; 
 height: 10px; 
 transform: rotate(45deg); 
 -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(45deg) translate(0px, 0px); 
-moz-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.0);
-o-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.0);
 margin-top: 0px;
 float: left;
 content: "";
 margin-right:5px;
 }

 label + .toggle-inbox:checked:after {
 border-right: 3px solid black;
 border-bottom: 3px solid black;
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 transform: rotate(-135deg);
-webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(-135deg) translate(0px, 0px);
-moz-transform: rotate(-135deg) scale(1.0);
-o-transform: rotate(-135deg) scale(1.0);
 margin-top: 0px;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-top:0px;
 content: "";
 }
 .toggle-inbox + div#text-content-details1 + .less {
 visibility : 0px ;

 }
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVNZJL

Please suggest

Comment: The less link works when you replace `a` with `span`.

Comment: @Jibbow, Yes, replacing `a` tag with `span` does solve the problem of the less link not working in firefox and internet explorer. Thanks.

Any idea why the toggle inbox is not hiding in firefox and internet explorer  and other issues mentioned ?

Comment: @Jibbow, The arrows are not showing in firefox and internet explorer but showing in chrome browser.

In firefox and IE, toggle inbox is instead showing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In order to make the less link work, you could replace its `a` tag with `span`. To get full funtionality you could add `cursor: pointer;` to the `span`.
- The checkbox is shown because you set `display: none;` but somewhere else also `display: block;`. The second one is overriding the first one. The correct code:

  ```
  .toggle-inbox {
       display: none;
       visibility: 0;
       float: left;
       }

  label +.toggle-inbox { /*you could also remove 'label' here*/
       cursor: pointer;
       /*removed display: block;*/
       font-weight: bold;
       line-height: 21px;
       margin-bottom: 20px;
       float:left;
       }
  ```
- After thinking about your 'arrows' I came to the conclusion, that you want to style the checkbox in order to look like an arrow, right?
  This can't be done easily. You usually hide your checkbox and add another  label to it. Trying to style a checkbox probably causes your third problem.
  Before I'll go on anwering here are a few think you have to change:

  - You should always put `input` on top of all `labels`. This is because in CSS you can select only the following elements.
  - You should change most of your `+` to `~`. This is because `+` only selects the *next* element. `~` is much more flexible as it selects the *following* elements. Therefore you could shorten `.toggle-inbox + div#text-content-details1 + .less` to `.toggle-inbox ~ .less`
  - You could shorten your CSS: `label +.toggle-inbox` is (almost) equal to `.toggle-inbox` (difference: first one selects all `.toggle-inbox` directly after any `label`; second one selects all `.toggle-inbox`)

So the whole code (cleaned up and hopefully correct):

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input class="toggle-inbox" id="_1" type="checkbox">

    <label class="label" for="_1">Stack OverFlow - Aim of Website - To discuss good questions about good code and code development</label>

    <div id="text-contents-details1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing. &nbsp;&nbsp;
      <label href="#clear" class="less" for="_1"><span id="less" style="color:darkorange;" class="arrow-less">Less</span></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.label {
  font-size: 29px;
}

.toggle-inbox {
  display: none;
}

.less {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle-inbox ~ div#text-contents-details1 {
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  clear: both;
}

.toggle-inbox:checked ~ div#text-contents-details1 {
  display: block;
}

.label::after {
  background-color: white;
  border-right: 3px solid black;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  width: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(45deg) translate(0px, 0px);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.0);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.0);
  margin-top: 10px;
  content: "";
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.toggle-inbox:checked ~.label::after {
  border-right: 3px solid black;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(-135deg) translate(0px, 0px);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg) scale(1.0);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg) scale(1.0);
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QjbboK definitly works with IE11 and Firefox 40 :)

Comment: Did it work or do you still have any questions? Feel free to ask :)

Comment: Sorry for late reply. 

The `span` instead of `a` worked perfectly. I do not know why the `a` tag does not work in firefox and IE and works in chrome.

Thanks for the same. 

But when I tried to add more items in the code for expanding / collapsing, they caused problems. 

Have a look - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gapxOW

Maybe the tilda is causing problem. The arrows of different divs are operating together and not independently of each other.

Comment: "The activation behavior of a label element for events targeted at interactive content descendants of a label element, and any descendants of those interactive content descendants, must be to do nothing." [W3C - HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element) says that the link *has to do nothing*.

Comment: Ah yes, alright! It is the tilda! To solve this problem you have to put a `span` or `div` around each "expandable block". See edited code example in my answer :)

Comment: That solves the problems @Jibbow

I have put multiple arrays here in this codepen - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avOyBz and I marked your answer as correct

Thanks

Comment: I would like to ask one question though. What would you recommend for using for purpose of mobile for toggling divs ? I would like something lightweight which does not slow the speed of the page and yet should be handled by android etc. mobiles

Comment: I am actually using this technique right now on a project and it works great! This is probably the best approach as it *is* lightweight and it can be handled by all browsers (except IE8 and lower) as long as it is 100% valid CSS (check it with W3C validator). Pure CSS is probably the fastest solution (JavaScript is usually slower)

Comment: I have found that some advanced functions like input:checked, :focus, etc. are not supported by mobiles or they cause very much lag in them.

Comment: You can easily check this out on caniuse.com :)